# Cant get rid of: AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replication, replicaset

In my mongod.log is a huge number of those errors:

```
2017-07-05T11:12:23.211+0200 I ACCESS   [conn788] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client 123.123.123.123 ; AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
```

I'm running a three member replica-set in

```
mongod-db.version()
3.2.11
```

I already added a admin-user by

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: 127.0.0.1/test
clustername:PRIMARY> use admin
switched to db admin
clustername:PRIMARY> db.createUser( { user: "admin",
...           pwd: "password",
...           roles: [ "root",
...                    "userAdminAnyDatabase",
...                    "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
...                    "readWriteAnyDatabase"
... 
... ] } )
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        "root",
        "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
        "readWriteAnyDatabase"
    ]
}
```

On each replica-member I can enter the mongo shell as admin an perform

```
clustername:PRIMARY> db.auth("admin","password")
1
```

The replica-nodes config only differs in the bind-section for the external interface.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 123.123.123.123,127.0.0.1


security:
  keyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo_keyfile
  authorization: enabled

replication:
  replSetName: clustername
```

The keyfile is accessible for the mongo-user. Permissions and ownership are identical on every node. md5shum is identical too.

Any idea what might go wrong?

Comment: Ever resolve this?

Comment: I could not get to the root cause. So I dropped the whole installation, reinstalled & reconfigured it. Now its working fine.